# Deleting overlapping inside same polygon using QGIS?

Tags: merge, overlapping-features, qgis-2.4

I have same polygon partially overlapped:
[image]

How to delete overlapping and merge it to same area?

I am using QGIS 2.4.0.

Answer (score 5):

First select the two overlapping polygons you want to intersect, enable editing then just merge them using `Edit-> Merge Selected Features`and 
Save edits.

Alternatively you could try and use the `Dissolve` feature.

Take a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/qgis-merge-intersecting-polygons-into-one-which-are-part-of-the-same-feature)

Answer (score 2):

The software you are using is key to the best approach.  However here are a couple of approaches in two of the most common GIS solutions (other GIS packages are available).

1. ARCGIS:  Use the [Integrate tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002s000000) in the data management tool box.  This is an excellent tool.
2. QGIS: use the snapping options in v.edit (GRASS - Processing Toolbox) as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69425/is-there-an-open-source-alternative-to-arcgis-for-desktops-integrate-tool).

There are other methods such as using clean and build (both in Grass and ArcGIS old Coverage format tools - if they still exist). Dissolving will not retain the boundary between the polygons, which might not be a problem to you.