# Merging multiple small overlapping polygons into one

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, overlapping-features

I have data like this.
[image: example]

I need to combine these overlapping polygons into a single polygon. I used merging of polygons, but it takes more processing time in QGIS.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Will this discussion [Merge intersecting polygons into one which are part of the same feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/merge-intersecting-polygons-into-one-which-are-part-of-the-same-feature) respond to your question?

Comment: Try Dissolve tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge intersecting polygons into one which are part of the same feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/merge-intersecting-polygons-into-one-which-are-part-of-the-same-feature)